# How can I calculate values for last 3 days for each date BigQuery SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a BQ table, for example

| barcode | orders | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "001" | 10 | "2020-04-18" |
| "001" | 9 | "2020-04-17" |
| "001" | 8 | "2020-04-16" |
| "001" | 7 | "2020-04-15" |
| "001" | 6 | "2020-04-14" |
| "002" | 20 | "2020-04-18" |
| "002" | 19 | "2020-04-17" |
| "002" | 18 | "2020-04-16" |
| "002" | 17 | "2020-04-15" |
| "002" | 16 | "2020-04-14" |

I want to calculate sum of orders for last 3 days for each date. Resul I expect:

| barcode | orders | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "001" | 27 | "2020-04-18" |
| "001" | 24 | "2020-04-17" |
| "001" | 21 | "2020-04-16" |
| "002" | 57 | "2020-04-18" |
| "002" | 54 | "2020-04-17" |
| "002" | 51 | "2020-04-16" |

So for "2020-04-18" it will be ("2020-04-18" orders) + ("2020-04-17" orders) + ("2020-04-16" orders), for each barcode. How can I do this in Google BigQuery? Can someone suggest a decision? Thanks you!

Comment: Your description is incompatible with the sample data.  The description is missing the orders from before the time period you care about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also you can try [ROWS](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/analytic-function-concepts#compute_a_cumulative_sum):

```
select
  t.*,
  sum(orders) over (partition by barcode order by date ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as cumulative
from t
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want cumulative orders with filtering.  Use a subquery:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(orders) over (partition by barcode order by date) as cumulative_orders
      from t
     ) t
where date > date_add(date, interval -3 day)
order by barcode, date desc;
```